# Alphabetical quicksort of Vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, quicksort

For the following code I've been trying to implement Quicksort to Alphabetically Sort a Vector of strings.

The issue I have found is that you cannot compare strings as ">" or "<".  I've also attempted using the .compare function for strings.

Any Advice?

```
`void quicksort(vector<string> arr, int left, int right)
 {
  int i = left, j = right;
  string tmp;
  string pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  /* partition */
  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
    }
}
/* recursion */
if (left < j)
    quickSort(arr, left, j);
if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}`
```

I Will also Later be attempting MergeSort, and InsertSort

Comment: `you cannot compare strings as ">" or "<"` What's stopping you?

Comment: Please don't use the `C` tag unless the question (and/or expected answers) is C. This is not.

Comment: `Any Advice?` arr is passed by value. Use a reference instead and you may get some sorted results..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I assume it is why the sort does not work..

Answer (score 2):

> The issue I have found is that you cannot compare strings as ">" or "<".

False. `std::string` provides overloaded `<` and `>` that you can use for comparison.

The problem you're having is that you're passing the `arr` argument by value. You should pass it by reference to be able to modify the original `vector` you passed to `quicksort`:

```
void quicksort(vector<string>& arr, int left, int right)
```